# Помогите разобраться в ошибке: Call to a member function get_checkout_order_received_url() on int

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в проблеме.
Сайт на ВП, установлен woocommerce + плагин Freekassa для оплаты товаров. В процессе заказа при успешной оплате клиента кидает на [https://сайтстоваром.ru/?wc-api=wc_freekassa&freekassa=success](https://xn--80aaf1arjcpdckb.ru/?wc-api=wc_freekassa&freekassa=success).
На этой странице получат ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот кусок кода, на который указывает ошибка

```
public function get_return_url( $order = null ) {
        if ( $order ) {
            $return_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
        } else {
            $return_url = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'order-received', '', wc_get_checkout_url() );
        }

        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_return_url', $return_url, $order );
    }
```

Пожалуйста, помогите, хотя бы намёк

Comment: <?php $order = 1; if ($order) { echo "Да"; } else { echo "Нет";}
У переменной со значением 1(int) есть функция get_checkout_order_received_url(), которую можно вызвать?

Comment: как я понимаю,  get_checkout_order_received_url() должен вернуть строку, а возвращает целое число. Прошу помощи!

Comment: Переведите ошибку и вникните в её СУТЬ если вы не понимаете еще что написано на английском.

Comment: Перевёл. Возможно я не прав в своём высказывании в прошлом посте. Если Вы знаете, как устранить ошибку, скажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас $order является целым числом, а не объектом типа WC_Order. Видимо, в функцию прилетает id заказа.

Используйте такую строчку для получения объекта заказа:

```
$order_obj = new WC_Order( $order );
```

и вставьте её перед

```
$return_url = $order_obj->get_checkout_order_received_url();
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь! Сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Ошибки больше нет, но перестал меняться статус заказа после оплаты

Comment: Поправил ответ, обе строчки, заменил на order_obj.

Comment: Благодарю, проверяю...

Comment: `public function get_return_url( $order = null ) {
  if ( $order ) {
   $order_obj = new WC_Order( $order );
   $return_url = $order_obj->get_checkout_order_received_url();
  } else {
   $return_url = wc_get_endpoint_url( 'order-received', '', wc_get_checkout_url() );
  }

  return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_return_url', $return_url, $order );
 }`

вот такой код. Статус не меняется до сих пор

Comment: А что, раньше менялся?

Comment: В том то и дело, что да. Все работало идеально, только ошибка на success странице была. Ошибку убрали и статус перестал меняться